# AttributeError: type object 'sklearn.tree._tree.TreeBuilder' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, decision-tree

I am using jupyter installed via Anaconda3. i cannot import DecisionTreeClassifier and getting the below error. Python version installed in Ananconda - 3.7.3.

Can someone help me here?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import tree 

music = pd.read_csv('music.csv')
X = music.drop(columns=['genre'])
y = music['genre']

modl = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
modl.fit(X,y)

predictions = modl.predict([[21,1],[22,0]])
predictions
```

**Error Message:**

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 import pandas as pd
>   ----> 2 from sklearn import tree
>         3 
>         4 music = pd.read_csv('music.csv')
>         5 X = music.drop(columns=['genre'])
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree__init__.py in 
>         4 """
>         5 
>   ----> 6 from .tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
>         7 from .tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
>         8 from .tree import ExtraTreeClassifier
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py in 
>        38 from ..utils.validation import check_is_fitted
>        39 
>   ---> 40 from ._criterion import Criterion
>        41 from ._splitter import Splitter
>        42 from ._tree import DepthFirstTreeBuilder
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree_splitter.pxd in init
>   sklearn.tree._criterion()
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree_tree.pxd in init
>   sklearn.tree._splitter()
>
> sklearn\tree_tree.pyx in init sklearn.tree._tree()
>
> AttributeError: type object 'sklearn.tree._tree.TreeBuilder' has no
>   attribute '**reduce_cython**'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I meet the same trouble ,and try to solve it .
Finally, I find  `conda update scikit-learn` in anaconda prompt is useful for me.
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFxJd.png)